# Define a pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex using 2 datetimes (dt_start and dt_stop) and a timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timedelta

With Pandas we can define a `pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex` using the following syntax:

```
rng = pd.date_range(dt_start, dt_stop, freq='5Min')
```

`freq` is a string.

I would like to define the same kind of DatetimeIndex using a timedelta as freq

```
td = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
rng = pd.date_range(dt_start, dt_stop, freq=td)
```

I did some uggly hack such as

```
rng = pd.date_range(dt_start, dt_stop, freq="%sMin" % int(td.total_seconds()/60))
```

but I wonder if there is not a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more robust way to get this is to use a DateOffset (which you can pass as freq to [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html)).

Since [microseconds is the smallest unit for a timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
In [11]: td = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5, microseconds=100)

In [12]: pd.offsets.Micro(td.total_seconds() * 10 ** 6)
Out[12]: <300000100 * Micros>
```

*Note: I think it's a good [enhancement request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6307) for this function to accept a timedelta object...*